# Как я могу выполнить QSqlRelationalTableModel::setFilter с оператором 'WHERE'?

Tags: c++, qt

Как я могу выполнить QSqlRelationalTableModel::setFilter с оператором 'WHERE' ???
Для примера:

```
JournalModel->setRelation(1, QSqlRelation("usb_devices", "Usb_Device_ID", "Serial_Number"));
JournalModel->setRelation(2, QSqlRelation("military_personnel", "Military_Person_ID", "Military_Person"));
JournalModel->setRelation(3, QSqlRelation("military_personnel", "Military_Person_ID", "Military_Person"));
JournalModel->setRelation(4, QSqlRelation("divisions", "Division_ID", "Division"));
```

Я пытаюсь выполнить это в лоб.

```
setFilter("Military_Person='%1' WHERE Role_ID=2")
```

Но терплю неудачу, неужели мне придётся разбить мою таблицу на две, чтобы в две колонки результирующего справочника подбирать поля с разных таблиц??  **

Comment: Но ведь filter это уже выражение where, просто без ключевого слова where. Как вы себе представляете такой sql запрос? `select * from table where Military_Person='%1' where Role_ID=2` ? Может вам `and` нужно использовать?

Comment: То есть, мне придётся делать две разных таблицы для того, чтобы отсортировать по конкретной роли??? Я пробовал использовать AND, не получилось.

Comment: отсортировать или отфильтрвать?

Comment: Отфильтровать. Оговорился. Тут смысл какой результирующий справочник имеет 2 поля которые берутся из 1 таблицы с 1 параметром, но для каждого этого поля есть своя роль(что логично с точки зрения БД). И вот мне нужно отфильтровать по колонке ответственных например, или только по колонке ответственных за учёт.

Comment: Вы очень абстракно изъясняетесь. Приведите в вопросе структуру бд и желаемый результат. А лучше воспроизведите ее на каком-нибудь [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) и дайте ссылку

Comment: Я думаю тут уже это не имеет смысла. В RelationTable два поля с одним названием, из-за этого setFilter не может выполниться, придётся делать костыль фильтруя по id записи 1го из полей. А не через связь заданную в Relation.